# Clearing dynamically generated table with data in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a jquery datatable which consists of an expand button on each row. When I click on the expand button, it expands the row, and shows another nested table with additional information.

The issue that I am having is that whenever I double click the expand button swiftly, the nested table gets populated with redundant records. My question is how can I refresh the previous data in the table ?

I am enclosing part of the sample code with this question as follows:

```
  $('.js-cars-list').on('click', '.js-expand-btn', function () {
            var value = $(this).attr('id');
            $('.js-expand-btn').text('+');

            if ($(this).parents('tr').hasClass('parent')) {
                $(this).text('-');

                GetCarDetails(value);
            }
            else {
                $(this).text('+');
            }

        });


function GetCarDetails(carId) {

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetCarDetails", "Cars")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { carId: carId },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {

                                    $.each(data.data, function (key, value) {

                                        $.each(value, function (k, v) {
                                            $(".mdl-data-table .mdl-data-table").append("<tr><td><a href=/Car/Detail?search=" + v.Id + ">" + v.Name + "</a></td><td>" + v.Model + "</td><td>" + v.RegNumber + "</td><td>");
                                        });

                                    });
                                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log('Error occured');
                }
            });
```

How can I clear this

```
$(".mdl-data-table .mdl-data-table").append("<tr><td><a href=/Car/Detail?search=" + v.Id + ">" + v.Name + 
"</a></td><td>" + v.Model + "</td><td>" + v.RegNumber + "</td><td>");
```

on next click and get it populated with fresh data ?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear your table before adding fresh Data into it.

Something like this

```
function GetCarDetails(carId) {

    // clear table data 
    $(".mdl-data-table").empty();

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetCarDetails", "Cars")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { carId: carId },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

            $.each(data.data, function (key, value) {

                $.each(value, function (k, v) {
                    $(".mdl-data-table").append("<tr><td><a href=/Car/Detail?search=" + v.Id + ">" + v.Name +
            "</a></td><td>" + v.Model + "</td><td>" + v.RegNumber + "</td><td>");
                });

            });
                        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error occured');
        }
    });
```

}

and one more thing

```
$(".mdl-data-table .mdl-data-table")
```

I dont see any difference in both classed used above so you can change that to

```
$(".mdl-data-table")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clear the table by using empty() function

```
$(".mdl-data-table").empty();
```